# Discord.js v13 Channel just created returns as undefined. async wait problem?

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord.js

I'm adding a function to my discord bot: When a member reacts to a message, create a channel for them (named with their username) if it doesn't already exist, then begin a quiz in that channel.

The function to create the channels works but it returns undefined to the calling function.

```
module.exports.setup_channel = function(guild, user) {

  let userchannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === user.username);

  if (userchannel) {
    console.log(`${user.username} already exists.`);
    return userchannel;
  }
  else {
    console.log(`Creating ${user.username}.`);
    
    guild.channels.create(user.username, {
      type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
      parent: '1087464585411436615',
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: guild.id,
          deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL'
        },
        {
          id: user.id,
          allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL'
        }
      ]
    })
      .then(async (channel) => {
        await channel.send(`${channel.id}`);
        return channel;
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }
}


module.exports.setup = async function(client, guildId, user, mode) {

  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);

  const userchannel = await this.setup_channel(guild, user);

  console.log(userchannel);

  // …..
```

On the first run of setup(), where the channel doesn't exist, the channel is created and it's id is written into the channel (to test), but the channel is undefined in the calling function and any attempt to reference it fails.

On running setup() again, where the channel now exists, everything works.

Is it some problem with waiting for the channel to be created?

```
Creating marq_andrew.
undefined
marq_andrew already exists.
<ref *2> TextChannel {
  type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
```

Comment: Are you sure `create` returns the new channel? Also, you shouldn't use usernames as channel names. You may consider using their id instead.

Comment: Yes, the create returns the new channel. That's why I send its id to it as a message to prove that. Also, I added a console.log to the .then and it shows that the channel is being created after the call, so its a problem with waiting

Comment: Yes there are risks using the member's user.username as the channel name but it would be a very strange thing to name the channel with their id. Who would recognise a channel named with a long integer like 701266704730161212 as theirs? I keep track of the relationship between user.id and channel.id in the code (not shown) once it has been created.

Comment: oops, I understand more about the warning about using username as channel name. Discord will transform strings set as the channel name (lower case and others) so that the match (channel => channel.name === user.username) some cases will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by making the setup_channel function async and returning the await of the channel creation, though I don't understand why the original code didn't wait for it:

```
module.exports.setup_channel = async function(guild, user) {

  let userchannel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === user.username);

  if (userchannel) {
    console.log(`${user.username} already exists.`);
    return userchannel;
  }
  else {
    console.log(`Creating ${user.username}.`);
    
    return await guild.channels.create(user.username, {
      type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
      parent: '1087464585411436615',
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: guild.id,
          deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL'
        },
        {
          id: user.id,
          allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL'
        }
      ]
    });
  }
}
```